# React Native: reuse promise parameter outside the promise?

Tags: react-native, promise

I defined a promise to fetch a query. I got a json array:

```
    fetch('query')
    .then(response =>response.json())
    .then(json => { blabla})
```

I want to reuse json as a function parameter outside the promise:

```
     render(){
     return(
    <View onLayout={this.myFonction(json)>
    </View>)}

    myFunction =(json)=>{ 
     var array = json.names
     array.maps(value => {
      return (
      <Icon        
        name='heart'
        type='emo'
        color='red'          
        onPress={this.onPressIcon(value)} />);
      });
    }
```

All I got is that it's undefined. 
Is it even possible to reuse a promise parameter?

Comment: Update your question with the actual code that is making the issue.

Comment: `.then(myFunction)`?

Comment: I updated with my problem

Comment: Where would `json` in your `onLayout` expression come from? No, you cannot get a value out of a promise without waiting for it.

Comment: because I didn't find a way to call my function in my view. I know it's bad

Comment: You shouldn't call asynchronous functions with side-effects from your view anyway. You should call them from your controller, and when the promise gets fulfilled you should update your view.

Comment: do you have any example?

Answer (score 1):

Here we are again @danaso :). Try to implement your component this way.

Your fetch method would set the component state:

```
fetch('query')
.then(response =>response.json())
.then(json => { this.setState({ array: json.names })})
```

So in the render method:

```
render(){
  const { array } = this.state;
  return(
    <View>
      array.map(value => {
        return (
          <Icon        
            name='heart'
            type='emo'
            color='red'          
            onPress={this.onPressIcon(value)} />
        )
      })
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling your fetch function? I'd place it in the `componentDidMount()`